# Javascript in xPages error

Tags: javascript, xpages

I have the following code in an xPage to use gridx.  When it runs for some reason it translates the > symbol in my second decorator function to & which causes the javascript interpereter to throw and error.  Can anyone see what is wrong?

```
<script>
require(
    [ 
      "gridx/Grid",
      "dojo/store/Memory",
      "gridx/modules/ColumnResizer",
      "gridx/modules/NestedSort",
      "gridx/modules/Filter",
      "gridx/modules/Bar",
      "gridx/core/model/cache/Sync",
      "dojo/domReady!" 
    ],

  function(Grid, MemoryStore, Resizer, NestedSort, Filter, Bar, Cache) 
  {
    var columns = [ 
        {id: 'ownerName', field: 'OccupantName', name: 'Name', width: '150px'},
        {id: 'propertyAddress', field: 'PropertyAddress', name: 'Property Name'},
        {id: 'contactInfo1', field: 'ContactInfo1', name: 'Contact Information 1', 
            decorator: function(value)
            {
                try
                {
                    if( typeof( value ) === "undefined" )
                        return "";
                    if( typeof( value ) === "string" )
                        return value;
                    myLen = value.toString().length;
  //  THIS WORKS FINE
                    if( myLen > 35 )
                        return value.join( "<br></br>" );
                    return "";
                } catch (e) 
                {
                    console.error('error decorating date: ' );
                }
            }
        },
        {id: 'contactInfo2', field: 'ContactInfo2', name: 'Contact Information 2',
            decorator: function(value)
            {
                try
                {
                    if( typeof( value ) === "undefined" )
                        return "";
                    if( typeof( value ) === "string" )
                        return value;
                    myLen = value.toString().length;
     //  THIS GETS TRANSLATED TO &gt;
                    if( myLen > 35 )
                        return value.join( "<br></br>" );
                    return "";
                } catch (e) 
                {
                    console.error('error decorating date: ' );
                }
            }
        },
        {id: 'myTier', field: 'MyTier', name: 'Tier'},
        {id: 'my', field: 'MyFloor', name: 'Floor'}
    ];

      // Make an AJAX call to look up the full data set and store it locally for fast access
  dojo.xhr.get({
    url:"xpRestSTAROccupantInfo.xsp/gridDataSTAROccupantInfo",
    handleAs:"json",
    load: function(restData){

      // Load the data into a local memory store
      var store = new MemoryStore({
        data: restData,
        idProperty: '@noteid'
      });

      grid = new Grid({
        id: "my_gridX",
        cacheClass: Cache,
        store: store,
        autoHeight: true,
        structure: columns,
        barTop: [
               "gridx/support/Summary",
               "gridx/support/DropDownPager",
               {pluginClass: "gridx/support/QuickFilter", style: 'text-align: right;'}
          ],
          barBottom: [
                "gridx/support/LinkSizer",
                {pluginClass: "gridx/support/LinkPager", style: 'text-align: right;'}
          ],

        sortInitialOrder: {colId: 'ownerName', descending: false},
        modules: [
            Resizer,
            NestedSort,
            Filter,
            Bar
        ]
      });

      //Put it into the DOM tree.
      grid.placeAt('gridX_Here');
      grid.startup();

    },
    error: function(msg, args) {
      console.error('Error loading grid data:  ' + msg );
      alert('There was an error loading the data:  ' + msg); 
    }
  });


  });
    </script>
```

Comment: That is crazy, it changed `>` into `&amp;`, not `&gt;`?

Comment: That's what it shows in firebug.
OK I TAKE THAT BACK.  Apparently that was me typing that.  My bad.  You were correct.  I will update the code it is &gt;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug might be the first > not being escaped, depending how you did put your function on the XPage.

Move the function into a script library, which is best Practise anyway.

Alternative use an ScriptBlock to keep it on the page. To get the format right add it to the page and paste your script through the properties. If you go for pasting into the source directly you might miss a tag.

Make sure it is static, not computed.

Comment: So not a Javascript guy really so I don't know how to do that.  In fact I tried to make the decorator function into a simple local function in a <script> tag and call it in the deorator : myFunc(value) but it kept telling me it couldn't find a reference to 'value' perhaps because all this code is in a <script> tag ?

Comment: That's a skill you need to acquire. Actually simple: copy your code into a Js library (that's a design element, make sure you use client side js for your case). Give your function a name. Then on the XPage add the library to resources and call it

Comment: Just copy the whole thing between the script tags to a js library. Where is the problem with that?

Comment: Tried the script library now I get :

Error loading grid data: TypeError: Grid is not a constructor
csJSBODLibrary Listing (line 103)
TypeError: Grid is not a constructor
grid = new Grid({

Comment: Check your js in firebug. I bet you have path errors (require not finding files). If you want to keep the js on the XPage replace the script tag with an xp:OutputScript

Comment: As for the require not working, the code functions as expected if I remove the second decorator function.  Not sure if it would if there were other issues???  
On the xp:OutputScript, I am not familiar with that and get errors that it can't be found.  If you mean ScriptBlock when I do that all my code displays as text in the browser.  Feeling very confused right now.  Anyway you can elaborate in more detail on your suggestions?  I know you are very experienced and incredibly smart with all this, but some of use are a bit slower..  Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: answer updated. Don't try working in the source code directly first. Paste your script through the properties